# Date type in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I'm new to MySQL and C#.

I stored certain values in a column with data type Date. I did not want the time, only the date to be stored.
On viewing these values using phpMyAdmin or MySql command line, I see them in the format:

**YYYY-MM-DD**

However, when I retrieve these values in to my web application, they are displayed in the following format:

**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM**  (the time is specifically 12:00).

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format you might want to see this too.

Comment: Thanks'! Bookmarked. Very useful information for beginners like me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the date to the format you like when you fetch the data, using `date_format()`:

```
select date_format(datecol, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This returns the value as a string.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for me. But I think that I'll use _DATETIME_ instead of _DATE_ next time on.. much less hassles.

Answer (score 2):

when you store in C# your date field, you use DateTime object. In this object when you don't specify the time part will be put a default value depends on Globalization.

You can study how DateTime works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Comment: But I'm converting the retrieved Date type value to a string (using **toString()**) and then printing that string.

Why then does the time appear in the resultant string?

Comment: @SinghSiddharth . . . By the time you are calling `toString()`, you are in C#, and the value is already being treated as a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't retrieve the value as a string from mysql.  Why?  Because if you ever need to do any operations on that value, such as adding a day, then you will need to parse it back into a `DateTime` again.  String parsing can be slow, and when it comes to dates they are prone to errors like misinterpretation of mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy formatting.

The problem you have is that .NET does not have just a `Date` type.  It only has a `DateTime` type.  So loading a MySQL `DATE` type, is going to get a `DateTime` with the time portion set to midnight.

There's no direct problem with that, except on how are outputting the result.  If you just call `.ToString()` without any parameters, or you implicitly use it as a string, then you are going to get a result with the full date and time.  You simply need to provide a parameter to indicate what formatting you want.

Without any parameters, you are getting the General `"G"` format.  This is explained in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx).

In other words:

```
yourDateTime.ToString() == yourDateTime.ToString("G")
```

You can read about all of the other formats available, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

In particular, if you just want the date, then you probably want to do this:

```
yourDateTime.ToString("d")
```

---

Based on your comments, you should be doing this instead:

MySQL Query:

```SQL
SELECT Gbstartdate FROM TblGbDef
```

C#:

```cs
DateTime gb_start_date = (DateTime) datareader[0];
```

Comment: Ok thanks'! I'll try all this too.  This is how I'm getting my work done right now:  _My Sql query_ :  SELECT date_format(Gbstartdate, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM TblGbDef  `DateTime gb_start_date = DateTime.ParseExact(datareader[0].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`  `TimeSpan days_elapsed_ts = current_date - gb_start_date;`  `int days_elapsed = days_elapsed_ts.Days;`